# Active child state stays active when it shouldn't using ng-class and ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-class

My current working on nested states (with many nested states) using ui-router and can get the state to change to an active state using ng-class like so

```
ng-class="{active:$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child<1-3>')}"
```

however id like add multiple states to the active class and achive this like so

```
`ng-class="{active:[$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child1'),$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.grandchild1')]}"
```

and it works, however when I click out of the state it stays active. I created this [codepen](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/rxMJyV). It looks like so.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Id like it if the `child1` tab isnt active while in the `child2` and `child3` states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just curious, where did you get the following syntax

```
ng-class="{active:[$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child1'),$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.grandchild1')]}"
```

If you change the value of the `ng-class` above to the following, it should achieve what you're looking for, i hope.

```
{active:$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child1') ||  $state.includes('sidemenu.parent.grandchild1')}
```

Comment: Thats what I tried (earlier and again just now) and is didn't seem make either of the states active doing that. I came up with the syntax I used by each expression in an array and do so works but doesnt make the state go un-active

Comment: i modified your code pen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjLYJG. 
does this fulfil your requirements?